# Distribution of conditional expectation?

Tags: distributions, conditional-expectation, conditioning

Let $X,Y$ be random variables with pdf $f_{X,Y}$. I would like to find the distribution of the random variable $\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)$, conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$. If a specific form of $\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)$ is given, then possibly using a simple transformation method suffices. If not, then examining $\mathbb{P}\{ \mathbb{E}(Y\mid X) \leq \xi \}$ seems not very insightful. I guess I am missing something perhaps obvious in that I actually have the necessary skills to derive the distribution but somehow did not see where to subtly employ?

Comment: Related: [Can we find a distribution of the conditional expectation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2439640)

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific with your problem; there is no one way of doing this that fits all situations well.

Comment: @jbowman, Thanks for feedback. I am interesting to see a proof of the impossibility of doing that as well.